# Can not call WindowUtils.getAllWindows()

Tags: java, jna

using JNA I am trying to run the following code.

```java
    private Rectangle getWindowDimensions(String appTitle) {
        for (DesktopWindow desktopWindow : WindowUtils.getAllWindows(true)) {
            if (desktopWindow.getTitle().contains(appTitle.toUpperCase())) {
                return desktopWindow.getLocAndSize();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am doing this on Windows 10, 64bit, and using IntelliJ IDE.

My imports for this file are,

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.WindowUtils;
import com.sun.jna.platform.DesktopWindow;
```

WindowUtils.getAllWindows() is the only bit of this code not able to compile.

The error I get is...

```
Error:(31, 55) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAllWindows(boolean)
  location: class com.sun.jna.platform.WindowUtils
```

Comment: Please clarify -- are you getting an error of some type? Or is the problem more of one of misbehavior? Please be as specific and clear as possible.

Comment: No error, it simply shows the method doesn't exist within the package `import com.sun.jna.platform.DesktopWindow;`

I was just reading the latest documentation, and checking it against my version. I am using this version, as the Javadoc shows, I should be able to access this method, as all the other methods seem to work fine.

http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/v7BtYc6.png

I suppose this counts as an error, but I felt I explained that this was the issue from the start. 

https://i.imgur.com/aiT6zkK.png

Comment: Can you show how you configured the dependency? Also, please [edit] your question to provide more information; code and errors should be presented as formatted text rather than images.

Comment: I will edit the main question with all that info now.

Comment: @Slaw thank you! I have posted my solution. You got me looking in the right spot, I had updated the version, but assumed it would replace the old version. It did not, instead it creating a separate, new dependency, which was not getting used.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I Had an older version of JNA not supporting this feature added as well, version 4.0.1, when checking my listed dependencies, removing the old version, fixed the issue!

Thank you @Slaw! You pointed me in the right direction to discover my mistake.